# How to stabilize this CV triggered toggle (555 timer latching switch) when fed with two gates?

Tags: transistors, 555, latch, trigger, synthesizer

I created the prototype for a modular synthesizer module. The **project goal** is an AND gate that is fed with two control voltage inputs (A and B with an Vpp around 5V). There will be two outputs: the AND itself and a binary (HIGH/LOW) which is toggled each time the AND is true. I'm referring to this as "toggle".

Toggles based on pulses:

[image: Toggles based on pulses]

Toggles based on gates:

[image: Toggles based on gates]

The **building blocks** are:

- An AND gate made of transistors.
- A comparator to have a buffered signal (based on a LM358 op amp) with a Vpp ~10V.
- The latching switch (based on a 555 timer). I took [common schematics](https://youtu.be/_uReSadp-KA?t=221), replaced the button circuitry with an inverting transistor (Q5) and added a 100uF capacitor (C2) to pin 6 and 2 to help keeping the HIGH state for a bit.

[image]

The **result** works pretty well with either only pulses on the inputs or a gate combined with a pulse. Only the combination of two gates leads to a **problem**: The behaviour is inconsistent, the toggle works only randomly.

See two short videos of the result on breadboard:

1. Working circuit based on pulses: https://youtu.be/dig6ZcPsWyI
2. Broken circuit based on gates: https://youtu.be/Vn5MXCvO_VI

**Question:** Do you have an idea how I can stabilize the behaviour when two gates are applied?

Thank you in advance!

*PS: Once it's working, I'll add buffering op amps at the outputs (with 5V Vpp).*

Comment: Why not use conventional logic gates? It seems a no-brainer to me. Not going to watch the videos, sorry. Embed the videos if you can. If you can't do that, then any question on this site that relies on an external video link is going to fail at some near-future point in time.

Comment: Think about the direction of the current through Q5 when the IC2 output is low.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I chose this transistor setup because I had it at hand.

Comment: Look closely at Q5. It is connected to the Toggle output, and when Toggle is low the CB diode shorts the BUFFERED AND output.